# Self Sizing Cells - new cells are not sized correctly

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, autolayout, uicollectionviewlayout, autosize

I'm using a Self Sizing Cells with the UICollectionView and AutoLayout and UICollectionViewFlowLayout subclass.

The problem I'm facing is that with some cells, only the first "screen" is being laid out correctly. When I scroll further, the "collection" layout breaks, while the content inside the cell is laid out correctly.

Especially the issue is manifested when displaying an Appstore-like content (table of horizontally scrollable lists).

It seems, that the UICollectionView doesn't update the sizes of the newest cells. How can this issue be tackled?

**Note**: This problem is easily fixed by setting the `estimagedItemSize` to be equal of the size of the cell.

**CollectionView calculates the correct size and origin for the first cells, but not the next ones, which are not visible**

**The problem is explain on the illustration below:**
[image]

**The actual screenshot captured from the running app with the problem:**

[image]

**Unedited version of the screenshot:**
[image]

Comment: Maybe this would help you: https://engineering.shopspring.com/misplaced-views-and-choppy-scrolling-with-dynamically-sized-collection-view-cells-4010c02fbaae

Comment: @Crazyrems thanks for mentioning it. I've read it already. However, the answer is "Not to use self-sizing cells" which makes it out of scope for this question.

If I had to migrate the project from the self-sizing cells, I'd prefer moving to something similar to the LayoutKit or Texture (AsyncDisplayKit).

Comment: I'm going to add a bounty, as soon as the question becomes eligible, since nobody is interested in trying to solve such issues.